# Why is my RxJava observable emitting a result before the function it calls is complete?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

In the code below, the loadMoreStrings() method is have it's call() method execute before the getLabelsFromServer() completes. I'm still learning RxJava but I just can't get this to run properly.

```
private void fetchLabels() {
        listObservable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> call() {
                return apiService.getLabelsFromServer();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        loadMoreStrings();
    }

    @Override
    public void loadMoreStrings() {
        stringListObservable.subscribe(new Action1<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<String> label) {
                myStrings.addAll(label);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Observable` type is lazy and it's not going to emit any items until you subscribe to it.

From code that you provided, you're not subscribing to `listObservable`. So it completes immediately and your `loadMoreStrings()` method is getting called.

Comment: It's subscribed in the loadMoreStrings() method.

Comment: If `listObservable` and `stringListObservable` are the same and you get an `onNext()` call, then it works properly, because otherwise you would get `onCompleted()` or `onError()`